# iPhone icon badge without a number

Tags: iphone, ios, badge

I have seen 1 answer to this question but was a solution for in app badges. I am looking to create a badge for the homepage icon without a number. It would just be a red dot.

Comment: Should I say again just "No" and rant about SO's force with at least 30 characters per post? =/

Comment: @JustSid: I filled in for you, you're welcome :P

Comment: And why would you *ever* want that? Perhaps you don't own an iPhone or understand how it works? I suggest you spend some time using the device before trying to develop apps for it. Your users will appreciate it.

Answer (score 10):

No public API permits setting a blank badge for your app icon. You may only specify a number, not a blank or any other character.

Comment: This answer is more than 8 years old. Is this still the case?

Comment: @user1032613: Unfortunately, yes. The Notification framework APIs only accept numbers for badges.